# MVC novice: are triad wrappers good/bad design?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

Academically, I'm familiar with the MVC paradigm, but practically speaking, I'm something of a novice. I'm implementing my first "real" MVC app (a video player in AS3).

I'm creating a playlist (as a sidebar to the video player). The playlist is scrollable, and when you hover on an item, it tweens (expands) to reveal more information. Nothing magical.

Now, there will be tens of playlist items. I'm wondering how to manage the actual M's, V's and C's here.

So, I've got an instance of an ItemModel, ItemView, and ItemController for each playlist item. When I want to append a new item to the playlist, should I be manually instantiating a new ItemModel, ItemView, and ItemController, link them all up, place them where they need to go, and [optionally] hang on to references to them?

What I'm thinking instead is creating an Item class which is just a simple wrapper for the MVC triad. Then, any client interactions with the triad have to be delegated by the wrapper. In this case, the Item "wrapper" is responsible for

1. Instantiating the MVC triad
2. Delegating events to the View.

Is this sensible? Extensible? Typical? Is it an anti-pattern?

In a larger system with more objects, I could see myself adopting a paradigm of the "MVCW" (with "W" being such a Wrapper for each triad), so 4 classes, of the form XyzModel, XyzView, XyzController, and Xyz (or XyzWrapper, or XyzObject, or whatever).

But... this doesn't come across as something I've read about before. And I'm aware that a given model can have multiple views, so how would that play in?

The motivation for all of this is that it seems a little silly to be manually creating 3 new objects for each new "thing" I need (especially in the case where client interaction will be so minimal). I suspect it's simply a misstep in my perception of the MVC paradigm, and that upon correction, not only will I understand why the "Wrapper" is a bad idea, but also come out with an understanding of how to better manage the actual objects in the triad.

Maybe, my design approach is wrong entirely, and that's the root cause of my confusion.

Or, maybe this is a special case where yes, in fact manufacturing 3 instances per list item **is** the correct procedure.

Any advice?

Comment: Why would you create 3 classes for every entity? Aren't model entites, controllers and views totally different things talking to each other?

Comment: Not three classes for each entry - three **instances** for each entity. One Model, one View, and one Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my understanding of when and where to use Models, Views, and Controllers was a bit flawed. For example, I wound up with only ItemView and ItemModel - all handled by a single instance of PlaylistController.

It seems as if the case for instantiating a full triad for (and only for) a single UI component is probably not very likely - and in the case it does happen, then it's more concise (and forward-compatible) to simply manufacture the associated objects outright.